# LWC Share CSS Style Rules doesn't work

Tags: lightning-web-components, css

I'm trying to create a share css style rule for my lwc components following the [doc](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.create_components_css_share) and it doesn't work

I created a LWC component like this

```
myStyle 
  --myStyle.css
  --myStyle.js-meta.xml
```

myStyle.css

```
:host() {
   --my-color: red; 
}
```

myStyle.js-meta.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<LightningComponentBundle xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <apiVersion>49.0</apiVersion>
    <isExposed>false</isExposed>
</LightningComponentBundle>
```

But when I tried to deploy this, I see this error

Error  force-app/main/default/lwc/myStyle/myStyle.js-meta.xml  No base file for markup://c:myStyle

And it deletes my files!!!

I added the Javascript and HTML files and when I tried to import the css module in another component I get this error: Unknown ref type slds for ref c/myStyle in file..

The doc also it's not very clear. What is the difference between the lwc component described in step 1 and the component in step 2?

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.create_components_css_share

Comment: Did you find a solution to this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was fixed in newer versions. After Summer ’20 is working